# Get Html and script from database and show in a div/grid/table

Tags: c#, jquery, webforms

I've this JQuery and html that I wish to show when user wants to be seen and I don't want it to load on page load I want it to load when user clicks the button. 
For example My jquery and Html is as following

```
<div id="dvSecondDiv" style="display: none;">
<script language="javascript">
    function ValidateUser() {
        var userid = $("#txtuserid").attr('value');
        var password = $("#txtpassword").attr('value');
        </script>
<input type="text" id="txtuserid"/>
<input type="text" id="txtpassword"/>
```

**now** this is saved in database in a table column 
 and there is only one column in the table
This is what I've done so far

I've used a grid

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="TestGrid">

</asp:GridView>
```

AND I'm binding the grid according to this 
there is no exception but nothing is shown either

```
 protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetData();
    }


    public void GetData()
    {
        var db= new TestDBEntities();
        TestGrid.DataSource = db.Htmls;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try This one

html div

```
<div id="dvFirstDiv" runat="server" ></div>
```

the button click

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GetData();
}
```

and the method

```
public void GetData()
{
    var db = new TestDBEntities();

    var sw = new StringWriter();
    var htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);


    var dg = new DataGrid();
    dg.DataSource = db.Htmls.ToList(); 
    dg.DataBind();
    dg.RenderControl(htw);
    dvFirstDiv.InnerHtml = sw.ToString(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to call `DataBind()` method.

```
TestGrid.DataSource = db.Htmls.ToList();
TestGrid.DataBind();
```

Comment: I've done that but that is not the issue as I said it does not render that HTML and script

Comment: You want to render html in gridvie?

Comment: YES in a proper way... when it actually renders the html and script tag they just down go along as they should

Comment: For example this line------ typeof window.lpTag._tagCount === 'undefined' is rendered as this -------typeof window.lpTag._tagCount === &#39;undefined&#39;

Comment: Then why are you using gridview ? SHow it in a div or someother element ?

Comment: How can I bind that with a div

Comment: you can loop on data and create dynamic divs.

Comment: I've just one record nothing more? How can I loop and bind that to an HTML DIV

Comment: only one row is returned which you want to show? 
`divData.InnerHtml = yourcolumnnamehere;`
here divData is a div with `runat="server`

Comment: I tried but its not taking the column name Not with EF